# How to import and export on Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: export, import, wolfram-cloud

I created a CDF document that imports images and exports output results.

```
Manipulate[ Dynamic@Row[{  Framed[before = Show[img, ImageSize -> 100]],Spacer[20],                 
Framed[Show[ColorConvert[before, "Grayscale"], ImageSize -> 100]] }], 
Row[{ Button["Import", 
img = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen",StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "*.gif"]]], Method -> "Queued"], 
Spacer[10], Button["Export", Export[StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[],"after.gif"],after]]}], 
AppearanceElements -> None, Initialization :> (img = Graphics[{Red,Disk[]}] )]
```

After that, I will upload this document on the Wolfram Cloud and use it.

However, imports and exports are not possible on Wolfram Cloud.

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8c556777-de84-458e-93b1-adffac512dd1

How to import and export on Wolfram Cloud?